# invalidate tags in addCase() function

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

UI language is stored in a redux store. I need to invalidate tags as a result of UI language being changed. So I need to dispatch an `invalidateTags` action from `addCase` function.

```
extraReducers: builder => {
        builder
          .addCase(settingsActions.setContentLanguages, <dispatch backendApi.util.invalidateTags(['Pages'])>
```

But there is no `dispatch()` there. What should I do?

Comment: Reducers are pure functions, they can't issue side-effects. Invalidate tags at the same time that `settingsActions.setContentLanguages` is dispatched.